# How to make a conical gradient in iOS using Core Graphics / Quartz 2D?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, gradient, radial-gradients

How can I draw such a conical gradient in iOS using Core Graphics / Quartz 2D API?

[image: Conical Gradient Sample]
<sub>(source: [ods.com.ua](http://ods.com.ua/win/eng/other/gimpdoc-html/painta27.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for a solution, Apple finally introduced `.conic` gradient type in iOS 12. Perfect for masking to create circular progress bar with gradient.

Example:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
gradientLayer.type = .conic
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.orange.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
gradientLayer.frame = bounds
```

[image: conic_gradient]

Comment: As .conic available from iOS 12 how we can achieve this in previous version(iOS 11)

Comment: You have to look for other solutions proposed in this question.

Answer (score 6):

Recently I've made a custom CALayer class for this: [AngleGradientLayer](https://github.com/paiv/AngleGradientLayer)

It's not tested for performance, so beware.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I wanted pure Swift solution for this, and it was also kind of a challenging task for me.

At the end, I wrote [AEConicalGradient](https://github.com/tadija/AEConicalGradient) which does that with interesting approach (by using a circle and drawing lines of different colors to the center).

[image: AEConicalGradient]

Answer (score 1):

There is no Quartz function for this style of gradient. Unless you're ready to dig into mathematics behind it, I'd suggest you use pre-made images for this. It's not a problem if you need it only for opacity mask.

Comment: It's very easy to do if you have to support <12, but in fact, they added it to 12 so it's now included in iOS

Comment: Where have they added it to CoreGraphcs? I only see .conic in CALayer, but CoreGraphics doesn't render .conic only radial and linear.