# CAShapeLayer’s strokeEnd doesn’t animate

Tags: ios, animation, cabasicanimation, cashapelayer

This is the code I’m using to animate my `CAShapeLayer`:

```
_progressBarLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(_progressToDrawForProgress(progress))

let progressAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
progressAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(1.0)
progressAnimation.fromValue = CGFloat(self.progress)
progressAnimation.toValue = _progressBarLayer.strokeEnd
progressAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)

_progressBarLayer.addAnimation(progressAnimation, forKey: "progressAnimation")
```

I’ve tested using the delegate to see if the animation plays, and it does. Logging start and stop in the right place.

This code is in a `setProgress(progress: CGFloat, animated: Bool)` function and runs if animated is true.

Is there anything glaringly obvious here?

Comment: Just FYI, _progressBarLayer is a lazy `CAShapeLayer` property

Comment: What does happen? Nothing, or does it jump immediately to the final value? What values do CGFloat(self.progress) and _progressBarLayer.strokeEnd have when you test it?

Answer (score 1):

Long answer: It turns out that the animation wasn’t playing because of something being drawn above the CAShapeLayer using quartz, so what I thought was the CAShapeLayer (that should be animated) was actually a Quartz drawing of that same layer.

Short answer: Don’t draw to the graphics context with Quartz

Comment: How did you go around making the animation? Did you use something else than CABasicAnimation?