# CAGradientLayer issues for animated circle created using CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cashapelayer, cagradientlayer

I am drawing an animated circle using the UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer. Now while adding the gradient effect the problem occurring is - CAGradientLayer  adds it's gradient effect from upside down. But I want gradient effect from the starting point of the circle  to the end point of the circle.

What I am getting is -

[image]

My code is - (it's a function)

```
 circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(radius+6,radius+6)  radius:radius startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(startAngle) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(endAngle) clockwise:isClockWise].CGPath;

    //circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-radius, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-radius);

    circle.fillColor = fillColor.CGColor;
    circle.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor;
    circle.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    circle.strokeEnd = percentToDraw/100;
    circle.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;

    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1.0);
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.0);
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width , self.frame.size.height);
    NSMutableArray *colors = [NSMutableArray array];
    [colors addObject:(id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [colors addObject:(id)strokeColor.CGColor];

    gradientLayer.colors = colors;
    [gradientLayer setMask:circle];

    [self.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];

    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = duration;
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;

    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:percentToDraw/100];

    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
```

How do I add gradient so that it starts(with red) and goes forward to finish point(with black). ?

Comment: I'm afraid I dont have an aswer but I do know that gradients start from one edge of a rect and slowly chnge color as they draw nearer the other edge. This is exactly what's happening here except you've masked it with the circle path. I'm not entirely sure this is possible with CAGradientLayer. Although it might be possible if you split up your rect into quadrants and applied a different gradient to each quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about a conical/angle gradient, then there is no system provided method for achieving that with CAGradientLayer. There are libraries such as [AngleGradientLayer](https://github.com/paiv/AngleGradientLayer) that try to provide this functionality, however, as with any 3rd party solution, it should be used with caution.

You can also look at approaches like ones discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534144/how-to-draw-a-gradient-arc-with-core-graphics-iphone) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29051754/recreate-apple-watch-fitness-tracker-progress-bar-gradient-on-cashapelayer-s/29088677#29088677), however they would require you to slightly refactor your logic.

Note that this suggestions would only work in a circular case.