# Draw Rainbow Gradient in Ellipse in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, gradient, ellipse

I'm a beginning programmer in Swift, and I'm attempting to draw an ellipse in swift with a rainbow gradient that fills it, similar to a color wheel.

I'm confused as to how to approach this.  I'm currently drawing the ellipse:

```
    let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.setFillColor()
    context.addEllipse(in: Rectangle)
    context.drawPath(using: .fill)
```

But instead of setting the fill color, I want to draw a rainbow gradient inside it.

I've looked at this gradient method:

```
context.drawLinearGradient()
```

But I'm not sure how to go about it.  If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: CGContext does not have built-in support for angular gradients. Some third-party libraries are available for this, for instance: https://github.com/paiv/AngleGradientLayer

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485468/drawing-an-angle-angular-conical-arcing-gradient-in-objective-c-ios-using