# Draw 3/4 of a circle with gradient of three colors

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cagradientlayer

I want to draw 3/4 of a circle with a gradient border, like this:

[image]

I can draw this circle with this code:

```
func createProgressLayer() {
     let startAngle = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
     let endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI * 2 )
     let centerPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 , CGRectGetHeight(frame)/2)

     let gradientMaskLayer = gradientMask()
     progressLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter:centerPoint, radius: CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 - 30.0, startAngle:startAngle, endAngle:endAngle, clockwise: true).CGPath
     progressLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
     progressLayer.fillColor = nil
     progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
     progressLayer.lineWidth = 4.0
     progressLayer.strokeStart = 0.0
     progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0    
}
```

But I want to add a Gradient effect, Please help. Thanks.

Comment: There's no built-in way to draw an angle gradient, only linear or radial (concentric). Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379234/how-to-make-a-conical-gradient-in-ios-using-core-graphics-quartz-2d

Comment: The easiest way would be adding a gradient view on top of the circle view and position the gradient view as per your requirements.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Can you please show code?