# CGGradient now drawing exact color on UIBazierPath

Tags: swift, cgcontext, cggradientref

I am using CGGradiant to draw a gardiant 3/4 cirlce using three colors starting with red to yellow to green. But CGGradiant always starting color from slightly yellow rather than red. I am using its because the start/end point i am giving in drawLinearGradient.But not sure what to do give then. Below is the code and attached result.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
     let path1 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                             radius: radius-20,
                             startAngle: startAngle,
                             endAngle: endAngle,
                             clockwise: false)

    let strokedPath = path1.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: strokeWidth, lineCap: .butt, lineJoin: .miter, miterLimit: 0)
    ctx!.addPath(strokedPath)
    ctx?.clip()
    let red = UIColor(red: 234.0/255.0, green: 34.0/255.0, blue: 34.0/255.0, alpha:1)
    let green = UIColor(red: 254.0/255.0, green: 187.0/255.0, blue: 3.0/255.0, alpha:1)
    let blue = UIColor(red: 69.0/255.0, green: 207.0/255.0, blue: 51.0/255.0, alpha:1)

    let gradient = CGGradient(
        colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
        colors: [red.cgColor, green.cgColor,blue.cgColor] as CFArray,
        locations: [0,0.5,1]
    )

    context!.drawLinearGradient(
        gradient!,
        start: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20),
        end: CGPoint(x: rect.width-10, y: rect.height-10),
        options: []
    )
```

[image: Gradiant circle]

Answer (score 1):

Your gradient is not the right type. Right now the gradient starts from the top left and travels to the bottom right. This is called a linear gradient.

[image: Linear gradient]

This is why you see red on the top left, yellow in the top right and bottom left, and green on the bottom right.

What you want is a conic gradient, similar to the following image.

[image: Conic gradient]

Unfortunately CGGradient does not define simple methods to create this (as [this SO page says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379234/how-to-make-a-conical-gradient-in-ios-using-core-graphics-quartz-2d)), so use one of the recommended frameworks or google for one using the term "iOS conic gradient".

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yeah i understand that its not conic but linear but wondering if by placing some values around i can get the desired result.

Comment: @Mini2008 I cannot think of anything obvious from the top of my head unfortunately.